# A nice problem about a number theory problem containing combinatorics!

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, combinations

Prove that for any set $ A$ that is finitely positive integers, there exists a subset $B$ of $ A$ such that the following conditions are satisfied:

$i)$ if $b_1 \in B $ and $b_2\in B$ are distinct elements, then $b_1$ and $b_2$ are not multiples of each other, and neither are $b_1 + 1$ and $b_2+1.$ ( I mean $b_1$ is not divisible by $b_2$ and $b_2$ is not divisible by $b_1$)

$ii)$ for each $a \in A$ \ $ B ,$ we can find $b \in B$ such that either $a \mid b$ or $b+1 \mid a+1.$

I am very stuck with this problem , I have thought for days but no idea for this problem .Originally , my idea was to be inductive on the number of elements of A.That is, I assume that for every setA containing n trials that are satisfied, then every setAcontaining n+1 elements also satisfies . But the a|b condition keeps me from mining . So my guess is that this problem needs an algorithm to solve ! So I just want to ask everyone for a suggestion. I hope to get help from everyone. Thanks very much!

Comment: How can $b_1,b_2$ be multiples of each other?

Comment: @lulu I believe that is intended to mean that neither is a multiple of the other.

Comment: What happens if $A=\{2,3\}$?

Comment: @PeterMüller  Well, if we imagine that the condition was meant to read that $b_1$ does not divide $b_2$, nor does $b_2$ divide $b_1$ (and similarly for the $b_i+1$) then I suppose $B=A$.  After all it is true that $2\nmid 3$, $3\nmid 2$, $3\nmid 4$, and $4\nmid 3$.  And condition $ii$ is vacuously satisfied.

Comment: Indeed, any two element set works.  If $A=\{a_1, a_2\}$ with $a_1<a_2$.  Then, if $a_1\,|\,a_2$, take $B=\{a_1\}$.  If $a_1\nmid a_2$ but $(a_1+1)\,|\,(a_2+1)$, again take $B=\{a_1\}$.  If $a_1\nmid a_2$ and  $(a_1+1)\,\nmid \,(a_2+1)$, take $B=A$.

Comment: @lulu I mean $b_1$ is not divisible by $b_2$ and $b_2$ is not divisible by $b_1$. I will edit the post.

Comment: @PeterMüller I think B = {2,3} . Did I say something wrong?

Comment: What about A = {1, 2, 4}?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler I think $B =$ {  4  }

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @markvs   Originally , my idea was to be inductive on the number of elements of $A . $That is, I assume that for every set$ A$ containing $n$ trials that are satisfied, then every set$ A $containing $n + 1$ elements also satisfies . But the $a|b$ condition keeps me from mining . So my guess is that this problem needs an algorithm to solve ! Hope to get help from you.

Comment: You should include it in the Q.

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $S$ of integers, define the *maximal elements* of $S$ to be those $s\in S$ which do not divide any $t\in S$ besides $t=s$. For example, the maximal elements of $\{1,2,4,9\}$ are $4$ and $9$. Initialize $A_0=A$, and let $B_0$ be the maximal elements of $A$. Then, given $(A_i,B_i)$, define
$$R_i=\big\{x\in B_i : \text{there exists some }y\in B_i\text{ with }x\neq y\text{ and }y+1\mid x+1\big\}.$$
Define $A_{i+1}=A_i\setminus R_i$, and let $B_{i+1}$ be the maximal elements of $A_i$. We claim that, for some $i$, $R_i=\emptyset$, and that then $B_i$ satisfies the desired property.

The intuition for this is as follows: we start with a set $B_0$ which satisfies (ii), and then figure out where (if at all) it fails to satisfy (i). By definition, no two distinct members of $B_0$ may divide one another, so the only issue is if $y+1 \mid x+1$ for some distinct $x,y\in B_0$. If this happens, we must remove either $x$ or $y$. We'd rather remove $x$, since then $a=x\in A$ still satisfies condition (ii) with $b=y\in B_0$. However, once we remove $x$, condition (ii) may fail -- there may be some $a\in A$ which divides no element of $B_0$ besides $x$. So, we recompute the maximal elements of $A$ with $x$ removed, with the knowledge that $y$ is still a maximal element (and so condition (ii) is still satisfied at $x=a$), and continue this process until it halts.

---

Now for the proof:

Firstly, it is easy to see why some $R_i$ must be empty. Until $R_i$ is empty, the size of $A_i$ decreases at each step:
$$|A_0|>|A_1|>|A_2|>\cdots.$$
Since $|A_0|=|A|$ is finite, the size of $A_i$ can only decrease finitely many times, and so eventually $R_i=\emptyset$.

We now claim that, if $R_i$ is empty, $B=B_i$ satisfies condition (i). Indeed, by the definition of a maximal element, there exist no distinct $b_1,b_2\in B$ with $b_1\mid b_2$, as otherwise $b_1$ would not be maximal. In addition, if $b_1+1\mid b_2+1$ for $b_1,b_2\in B$ distinct, then $b_2$ would be in $R_i$. Since $R_i=\emptyset$, this cannot occur. So, the set $B$ given by this process satisfies condition (i).

Finally, we'll show that $B_i$ satisfies condition (ii) for every $i$, by induction on $i$. For the base case of $i=0$, assume $B_0$ fails to satisfy (ii), and let $a$ be the largest element of $A\setminus B$ such that $a\nmid b$ for every $b\in B$. Since $a\not\in B$, $a$ is not a maximal element of $A$, and so there exists some $a'\in A$ with $a\mid a'$. Clearly, $a'\not\in B$. However, since $a$ was chosen to be the largest element of $A$ satisfying its definitional property, $a'$ must divide some element $b$ of $B$, and so $a\mid a'\mid b$, a contradiction.

For the inductive step, we first show that
$$B_i\subset B_{i+1}\cup R_i\tag{$\star$}.$$
The proof is by contradiction: consider some $b\in B_i$ which is neither in $B_{i+1}$ nor $R_i$. Since $b\not\in R_i$, we know $b\in A_{i+1}$; however, since $b\not\in B_{i+1}$, there exists some $b'\in A_{i+1}$ with $b'\neq b$ and $b\mid b'$. However, since $A_{i+1}\subset A_i$, such a $b'$ would mean that $b$ is not a maximal element of $A_i$, contradicting $b\in B_i$.

We now proceed with the inductive step. Fix $i$, and assume that, for every $a\in A$, there exists some $b\in B_i$ for which either $a\mid b$ or $b+1\mid a+1$ (if $a\in B_i$, we simply take $a=b$). Now, consider some $a\in A$.

- If there exists some $b\in B_i$ with $b+1 \mid a+1$, take the smallest such $b$. It is clear that $b\not\in R_i$, as $b\in R_i$ would contradict the minimality of $b$. This means by ($\star$) that $b\in B_{i+1}$, which is enough. (Note that this case covers the case of $a\in B_i$.)
- If $a\not\in B_i$ and there exists some $b\in B_i$ with $a\mid b$, we claim $a$ must be in $A_{i+1}$. Indeed, this would imply that $a$ is not maximal in any set that contains $B_i$ as a subset; in particular, $a\not\in B_j$ for any $0\leq j\leq i$. This means that $a\not\in R_j$ for any $0\leq j\leq i$, and so $a\in A_{i+1}$, as desired. Now, since $B_{i+1}$ is defined as the set of maximal elements of $A_{i+1}$, there exists some $b\in B_{i+1}$ with $a\mid b$, finishing the proof.

Comment: You probably wanted $x\neq y$ in the definition of $R_i$. But even with this definition the construction fails. So either your proof is wrong or you made another typo in the definition of $R_i$. Btw this is precisely why this kind of notation is so bad, it is instable with respect to typos since you are at no point explaining your intuition (even though it's pretty clear).

Comment: @PeterMüller I've fixed the definition of $R_i$. Could you point out an example where my construction fails, or a step in my proof that isn't correct?